# Can't install anything on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I've been trying to install pip and when I did, when I tried using it, I get an error `'Threading' module not found`

Then I decided to remove all my python since I had 2.7, 3.4 and 3.6 and reinstall

So I used `sudo apt-get autoremove python 3.4`
And I did the same for 3.4 and 2.7

After this, I found out my Ubuntu software center was uninstalled along with vlc and many other apps. I tried to install Ubuntu software center with `sudo apt-get install software-center` but i get error:

```
dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
    python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
    python3-dbus
    python3-pycurl
    python3-aptdaemon
    python3-apt
    lsb-release
    apport-gtk
    python3-gi
```

... It goes on till

```
    python3-xkit
    apport
    software-properties-gtk
```

I don't know what's happening....
Please what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Open the Linux Terminal , and run this command "sudo apt-install update"

Comment: Update the Ubuntu? Like with a bootable flash?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: python 2.7 is required for some Ubuntu softwares and it come installed in ubuntu by default. Try reinstaling it again to see if everything goes right

Comment: Open the Linux Terminal , and run this command "sudo apt-install update"

Comment: I did but same output

Comment: I just restarted the computer and I can only see a desktop... No taskbar or status. I opened a text file in desktop and it opened with Libre office and I can't even close it. The x icon is no where to be found